# How to provide constructor parameters to Resteasy resources loaded from reflection?

Tags: java, servlets, resteasy, undertow

I'm running Undertow as a simple Servlet container. I deployed Resteasy servlet:

```
    ResteasyDeployment restEasyDeployment = new ResteasyDeployment();

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("");
    Set<Class<?>> resourceClassSet = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class);
    restEasyDeployment.getActualResourceClasses().addAll(resourceClassSet);

    ServletInfo servletInfo = Servlets.servlet("RestEasyServlet", HttpServlet30Dispatcher.class);
    servletInfo.setAsyncSupported(true)
            .setLoadOnStartup(1)
            .addMapping("/*");

    DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo = new DeploymentInfo();
    deploymentInfo.setContextPath(path)
                    .addServletContextAttribute(ResteasyDeployment.class.getName(), restEasyDeployment)
                    .addServlet(servletInfo)
                    .setDeploymentName("api")
                    .setClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

    DeploymentManager deploymentManager = Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(deploymentInfo);
    deploymentManager.deploy();
```

This code is based on [this tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e1422) and [this code](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/server-adapters/resteasy-undertow/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/undertow/UndertowJaxrsServer.java).

How to provide any construction parameters to the resources deployed inside Resteasy?

I see tutorials using static fields but I want to keep dependency inversion in place for easy testing. In a Servlet world a right way of doing it would be to put everything in context.